# How can I install `bcrypt-as-promised` from an old code base onto my ubuntu box?

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I'm working with an old code base from an old project that uses `bcrypt-as-promised` (before `bcrypt` allowed the use of promises). When I try and `npm install` the `package.json`, I receive this error for that package:

> npm WARN deprecated bcrypt-as-promised@1.1.0: the bcrypt module supports promises now, this module is no longer necessary
>
> npm WARN deprecated bcrypt@0.8.7: bcrypt < v2.0.0 is susceptible to bcrypt wrap-around bug. Upgrade to bcrypt >= v2.0.0 for improved support for newer bcrypt hashes

And then proceeds to fail (I can paste more of the error message if needed).

I'm a little confused as to how I might be able to get this now deprecated package to install. I thought about modifying the codebase to only use `bcrypt` (with the now native promises supported), but I'm afraid of diving into a bee's nest and breaking the application. I was wondering first if there might be a way to install this package for the old code base to get it working.

Any thoughts? Thanks for your time and any insight you may have.

My package.json: https://github.com/twknab/mean_hike/blob/master/package.json

// Edit:

Here's the full terminal message I receive when I try and `sudo npm install`:

```
> bcrypt@0.8.7 install /var/www/mean_hike/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
'/var/www/mean_hike/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1072-aws
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" 
"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/mean_hike/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v11.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-11-27T10_46_27_925Z-debug.log
```

Comment: These are just warnings, which shouldn't break the installation – can you add any more error detail?

Comment: @Ben Thanks for your response--I did add the full terminal message there. I tried installing `node-gyp` as well but I still get the same message. I also tried installing `node-gyp rebuild` as I see it mentioned in the error but again, receiving the same msg. Any insight you can provide would be immensely appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue was to use `yarn` to import all of my dependencies rather than `npm`, while also swapping `bcrypt-as-promised` for `bcrypt` (which now includes promises with no syntax changes necessary).

1. I ditched `bcrypt-as-promised` and replaced it with `bcrypt` in my `package.json` file.
2. I then changed any instance of `require('bcrypt-as-promised')` to `require('bcrypt')` (the syntax for using `bcrypt` remains the same, just the dependency importation lines need to change).
3. Without using `yarn`, even after changing my folder permissions, I was *still hitting permissions "EACCES: permission denied" errors*, with only `bcrypt` failing. My versions of npm and node seemed fine. Made sure my Ubuntu box was all updated.
4. That's when I gained the suggestion from a wise friend to try using `yarn` to grab the dependencies instead. I ran `yarn import` which reads the `package.json` file and creates a `yarn.lock` file. I then installed `yarn` on my ubuntu machine (`sudo npm install yarn -g`), and ran `yarn install`, and **`bcrypt` successfully installed!**

## Update Jan 2019 - Improved Solution

It looks like if `npm` dependencies were originally installed using `sudo`, permission issues can be experienced when trying to install `bcrypt`. My improved solution was to:

- Nuke the `./node_modules` folder via `sudo rm -r ./node_modules`
- Install npm packages fresh (not using `sudo`).
- After this, I was able to `npm i --save bcrypt` with the package installing
  successfully.

Here's a link from GitHub that helped me find the solution and an excerpt:

> @Mayocampo permission denied, mkdir
>   '/home/someroute/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
>
> It seems you run rpm as root, therrfore your account cannot `mkdir`
>   under /home/someroute/node_modules/ Check dir with `ls -l
>   /home/someroute/node_modules/` Im sure owner of upper dir is root. or
>   your account cannot have permission.
>
> I guess there are two options are available.
>
> 1. `sudo rm -r ./node_modules` And install package via npm
>      again, but without using sudo.
> 2. Change mod ./node_module to access and excutable. I decided first, and its fixed

Source: [juicycool92 @ GitHub](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/590#issuecomment-386928167)

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of bcrypt can be quite tricky to install, and it looks like you're hitting a classic permissions issue with npm. You can try some of the tips listed in the official documentation here: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

… but in the meantime, here are a few things to try:

1. Attempt a global install of node-gyp first, either with or without
   sudo: `npm install node-gyp -g`
2. If that works, *then* try installing
   bcrypt (again, globally).
3. If you're still seeing permissions issues,
   you may need to sort out ownership of your `node_modules` directory:
   `sudo chown -r XXX /usr/lib/node_modules/` (assuming that's where
   the global modules directory is on your machine of course).

Comment: Thx for your response. I did install `node-gyp` per your suggestions but have same issue. I tried changing global permissions for my `~/node_modules` and my `/var/www/mean_hike/node_modules` folder per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16151707/6685623). When I tried running `sudo chown -r` and tried to supply permissions got msg that `-r` was not a valid flag? I have 2 `node_modules` folder on my ubuntu instance (both in project folder and the in root user dirs). Don't need `bcrypt-as-promised` globally per say. What should my `node_modules` (project folder) permissions be?

Comment: I also just tried: `sudo chown -R $USERNAME ./node_modules` (from within the project directory), and also `sudo chown -R $USERNAME ~/node_modules` (where the global folder lies). In my case $USERNAME = "ubuntu" (per AWS deployment)....wondering why I'm still hitting these permission errors...hmmm

Comment: I tried running: `sudo chown -R ubuntu ./*` (where `ubuntu` is system username) from within my project directory, and that seemed to work momentarily allowing me to `sudo npm install` without any errors. But when I tried to run the server it appeared the packages did not successfully install -- when I tried to manually install bcrypt or bcrypt-as-promised, e.g, `sudo npm install bcrypt -g --save` I got the same ole error...gunna have to step back and think more...really don't want to give up this code base entirely and just get her moving again even for a short while :D :D

Comment: Bizarre… I'm assuming there's nothing of note in `/home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-11-27T10_46_27_925Z-debug.log`?

Comment: It's so weird, it seems if I change the permissions nothing matters. I even tried switching to a different version of Node (that I had used back when building the project). I see some other stuff online about the EACCES: permission denied message in regards to bcrypt, but seems like some folks have different solutions (none of which are still working for me)....going to keep wrestling this in bits and see if I can figure out *why* and find a remedy. This project is a few years old running Ang1.x and I had put 100+ hours into it, just wanting to keep it alive a bit longer... =)

Comment: I ended up just using `yarn` to install my dependencies and it worked! I also ditched `bcrypt-as-promised` for `bcrypt` and I got my project running! Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: I found some insight into this issue from a month+ ago..looks like I originally installed my npm packages using `sudo`, because of this for some reason `bcrypt` specifically will have permission issues. I had to remove my `node_modules` and reinstall everything fresh without using sudo. I was then able to install bcrypt. I added this to my answer above, but just wanted to let you know unless you ever experience this again! Wishing you the best!